# How to solve loss of captcha images using Sitecore and Webforms For Marketers (WFFM)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm using Sitecore in combination with Webforms For Marketers (WFFM). I'm using the standard included captcha  form field. When I press on F5 (page-refresh) the captcha  refresh and audio button are not displayed. By the second F5 the captcha refresh and audio button are on screen again.

When I access direct the captcha refresh image the same problem occured by page refreshing (F5), but with a more detailed error message now.

```
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset]
   System.DateTimeOffset..ctor(DateTime dateTime) +13946944
   Sitecore.Resources.Media.Streaming.Preconditions.IfModifiedSincePrecondition.CheckRequestPreconditionAndSetResponseStatus(HttpContext context) +149
   Sitecore.Resources.Media.Streaming.RangeRetrievalResponse.ExecuteRequest(HttpContext context) +93
   Sitecore.Support.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler.DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context, MediaRequest request, Media media) +716
   Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler.DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +477
   Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +67
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +913
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

*URL = http://sitecore.local/~/media/Web Forms for Marketers/Icons/refresh.png*

I have searched the internet for this specific problem, but I can't find a solution for this situation (Sitecore and WFFM). Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

**UPDATE 27-02-2014** - I see that by a not working refresh or audio image, the web browser add this header to the request.

```
If-Modified-Since   Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: So from what I understand, the captcha shows up on refresh and not on initial page load?

Comment: No, the captcha shows up on initial page load and not on refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create the images (captcha refresh and audio image) in the Sitecore Media library in all languages. That solves the problem.